# Plotting a choropleth map (with geopandas) using a user_defined classification scheme

Tags: python, user-defined, choropleth, geopandas, bins

I'm kind of new to python, so I'm hoping that the answer to my question is relatively straight forward.

I'm trying to make a choropleth map using geopandas. However, since I'm making multiple maps that need to be compared to each other, it is indispensable that I use a custom data classification scheme (rather than quantiles or jenks). Hence, I've been trying to work with the User_Defined scheme, and I'm able to create the bins but I don't know how to apply them to the map itself.

This is what I did to create my classification scheme:

```
    import pysal.esda.mapclassify as ps
    from pysal.esda.mapclassify import User_Defined

    bins = [5, 20, 100, 600, 1000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 400000]
    ud = User_Defined(projected_world_exports['Value'], bins)
```

(where 'Value' is the column I plot in the map)

And then when I try to plot the choropleth map I don't know what the scheme is meant to be called

```
    projected_world_exports.plot(column='Value', cmap='Greens', scheme = ?????)
```

If anyone could help I would be hugely appreciative!

Thanks x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at the code of geopandas plotting function (https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/plotting.py) but I guess the `plot` method only accepts one of the three name ("quantiles", "equal_interval", "fisher_jenks") but not directly a list of bins or a `pysal.esda.mapclassify` classifier such as `User_Defined`.
(I guess it could be linked to that [issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/235) where the last comment is about defining an API for "user defined" binning).

However for now I guess you can achieve this by slightly modifying and reusing the functions from the file I linked.
For example you could rewrite you're own version of `plot_dataframe` like this :

```
import numpy as np

def plot_dataframe(s, column, binning, cmap,
                   linewidth=1.0, figsize=None, **color_kwds):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    values = s[column]
    values = np.array(binning.yb)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    ax.set_aspect('equal')

    mn = values.min()
    mx = values.max()

    poly_idx = np.array(
        (s.geometry.type == 'Polygon') | (s.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon'))
    polys = s.geometry[poly_idx]
    if not polys.empty:
        plot_polygon_collection(ax, polys, values[poly_idx], True,
                                vmin=mn, vmax=mx, cmap=cmap,
                                linewidth=linewidth, **color_kwds)

    plt.draw()
    return ax
```

Then you would need to define the functions [_flatten_multi_geoms](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/plotting.py#L11) and [plot_polygon_collection](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/plotting.py#L42) by copying them and you are ready to use it like this :

```
bins = [5, 20, 100, 600, 1000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 400000]
ud = User_Defined(projected_world_exports['Value'], bins)

plot_dataframe(projected_world_exports, 'Value', ud, 'Greens')
```

Comment: thanks for answering so quickly!

I'm afraid I don't know what the _flatten_multi_geoms and polit_polygon_collection functions are or how I'm meant to 'copy' them... Also, am I meant to equate 'binning' to something in the second line? Sorry if these questions are really simple; as I said, I have very little experience on python.

Comment: Concerning your first question, I just meant to copy them for example in your current working file/script or in your interpreter, in order to have them defined when you will use the `plot_dataframe` function. Concerning your second question, yes the arguments (such as `binning`) have to be defined when you are calling the `plot_dataframe` function; it will be done when you actually call it, at the end of the example: `plot_dataframe(projected_world_exports, 'Value', ud, 'Greens')` with your `geodataframe`, the name of the field, etc..

Comment: Glad it worked ! (you may consider to accept this answer if it helped you!)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative approach that does not require modifying the geopandas code.  It involves first labeling the bins so that you can create a custom colormap that maps each bin label to a specific color.  A column must then be created in your geodataframe that specifies which bin label is applied to each row in the geodataframe, and this column is then used to plot the choropleth using the custom colormap.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

bins = [5, 20, 100, 600, 1000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 400000]

# Maps values to a bin.
# The mapped values must start at 0 and end at 1.
def bin_mapping(x):
    for idx, bound in enumerate(bins):
        if x < bound:
            return idx / (len(bins) - 1.0)

# Create the list of bin labels and the list of colors 
# corresponding to each bin
bin_labels = [idx / (len(bins) - 1.0) for idx in range(len(bins))]
color_list = ['#edf8fb', '#b2e2e2', '#66c2a4', '#2ca25f', '#006d2c', \
              '#fef0d9', '#fdcc8a', '#fc8d59', '#e34a33', '#b30000']

# Create the custom color map
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('mycmap', 
                                         [(lbl, color) for lbl, color in zip(bin_labels, color_list)])
projected_world_exports['Bin_Lbl'] = projected_world_exports['Value'].apply(bin_mapping)
projected_world_exports.plot(column='Bin_Lbl', cmap=cmap, alpha=1, vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

Comment: Seems like a terrible amount of work for a relatively simple feature. Has there been any update on this?

Comment: Yes, please check the answer I have written below. 
Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66235068/6044608

Answer (score 3):

This can be done easily using **UserDefined** *scheme*. While defining such scheme, a *mapclassify.MapClassifier* object will be used under the hood. In fact, all the supported schemes are provided by *mapclassify*.

For passing your bins, you need to pass them in *classification_kwds* arguments.

So, your code is going to be:

```
projected_world_exports.plot(
    column='Value', 
    cmap='Greens', 
    scheme='UserDefined', 
    classification_kwds={'bins': bins}
)
```